# How to format numbers into a specific width in python?

Tags: python

How would you format this??

```
for i in range(11):
    print(i)
```

so it would look like:

```
 0
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
10
```

instead of:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

I would like all the single digits to be pushed into 2 spaces, instead of 1

Answer (score 9):

This is [the new way](http://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
print("{:>2}".format(i))
```

This is the [old printf-like way](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting):

```
print('%2u' % i)
```

Comment: Your answer is more comprehensive than mine was, go for it. :)

Comment: +1. But I'd reverse the order and put the new way before the old way.

Comment: Fixed links to point to python3 docs >_>

Comment: Also, for %-formatting, you're really supposed to use a `tuple` of format parameters, even if there's only one of them, so `print('%2u' % (i,))`.

Comment: If format requires a single argument, values may be a single non-tuple object (quoting docs verbatim).

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can use the format specifier, but you can also use `str.rjust`

```
print str(i).rjust(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or, you can do

```
"%2d" % 5
```

to output " 5"